# End turn by Drawing from Bottom card after Triple Slap?

Tags: exploding-kittens

By the rules of Exploding Kitten (Party Pack). If the slapped player put another slap, it will be added. (e.g: player 1 put double slap, player 2 put triple slap, total is 5 slaps to be done by the targeted player)

We had a situation where one of us got 8 slaps, but he ended all the 8 turns by using "Draw from Bottom" card because the field guide says "End your turn by drawing the bottom card from the Draw Pile". While SKIP and REVERSE specifically say "only ended 1 of your turns".

Can someone explain if the "Draw From Bottom" can really end all 8 turns?

Comment: It seems to me that "end 1 of your turns" and "end your turn" mean the same thing.  If each slap is a turn, then ending your turn ends one.  If all slaps together are one turn, then that would apply to SKIP as well.  (I don't actually know the game, though.)

Answer (score 5):

I see from the rules that the slap cards give multiple turns, not multiple draws.  Thus, the only cards that will allow you to avoid those extra turns are the Slap cards, which explicitly pass all your remaining turns to your target.

"Ending your turn" in general only affects the current turn, not your next turn or the turn after.